# Cross Product of 2 random unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, vectors, normal-distribution, cross-product

I have 2 unit-length vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ : $d_1$ and $d_2$ which are distributed uniformly over the unit-sphere. What will be the distribution of the direction of cross product of these vectors ?

By intuition, it seems that the cross product should be uniformly distributed over a unit sphere too. I tried to prove this starting from the way $d_1$ and $d_2$ were produced (by sampling 3 values from a standard normal distribution and getting a unit-length vector from the vector of those 3 values), but could not reach anywhere.

I am looking for a formal proof, so if anyone can help directing with that, it would be great.

Comment: How do $3$ values from a standard normal distribution give you a unit vector uniformly at random?

Comment: @Servaes http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html last method for sampling points uniformly over a sphere. There is also a formal proof stated at http://corysimon.github.io/articles/uniformdistn-on-sphere/ alternative-method-1.

Comment: I would argue along the lines of that the distribution of cross-product directions is rotation-invariant, so it has to be the uniform distribution.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate formally on your argument ?